# Navbar collapse in Bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to override the threshold at which my navbar collapses in Bootstrap 2 (using class="nav-collapse collapse").

I only have a few navigation items, and plenty of blank space, so I see the wide threshold as a bit unnecessary.

Comment: If this helped you please consider marking the answer as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `nav-collapse` class in the `bootstrap.css` file. Look at what the media query is and override it in your custom CSS. More than likely BS 2 also converts at 768 pixels